# Can not parse json object when using templateHTMLrenderer in django

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm beginning with django and JSON and I'm trying to send the list of patients in JSON using the code bellow:

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer,))
@csrf_exempt
def patient_list(request):
    """
    List all records, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #data = Patient.objects.all()
        data= Patient.objects.all()
        #serializer = PatientSerializer(data, many=True)
        #return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
        return Response({'patients': data}, template_name='records.html')
```

In records.html, I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = "{{patients}}";
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
</script>
...
<h2> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(data);</script></h2>  This is not actually true, I'm trying to figure out how to do it
```

However, when printing data (in string just to see what I have) I'm receiving something like that

```
 [<Patient: Patient object>, <Patient: Patient object>, <Patient:  Patient object>, <Patient: Patient object>, <Patient: Patient object>, <Patient: Patient object>, <Patient: Patient object>]
```

From my understanding it is not necessary to serialize data when using Response so I did not do it. I just want to get the list of patients and print their firstName for instance. Any help about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use the JsonResponse class that Django provides if you want to do it the long way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects. But since it looks like you're using DjangoRestFramework, in that case, you might want to consider just making a serializer class and then just making a ViewSet.

```
in seralizers.py:

from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = MyModel

in views.py:

from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import MySerializer

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

  serializer_class = MySerializer
  queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

in urls.py:

from rest_framework import routers
from .views import MyViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'mymodel', MyViewSet)
```

Comment: Thank you agrasley. I was using this way before, but then I wanted to use a specific html template in my answer so I used Response which takes also a template.html. The problem is that it seems that the return of patient_list is not correct in this case.In addition,